# Noindex individual sharepoint 2007 page

Tags: sharepoint

I want to hide one individual page from google. How can I do it?
I have a UserControl for this page.

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the robots.txt approach first. Refer to the description here http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

Write a robots.txt in the root of your site, make it accessible to anybody for read and put

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /<your_page_url>
```

there

Comment: if it works, mark the answer as an answer so other guys find it as a solution for them. otherwise write me so we can figure out another solution.